# TypeError when writing to text file with write()

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files, typeerror

I am working on a program to count anglicisms in German texts and everything works fine except when trying to output the results to a text file (at the bottom of the code). Here's my code so far:

```
from collections import Counter
import os.path

print('='*50)
print('Welcome to the ANGLICISM COUNTER 5000')
while True:
    print('='*50)

    lines, blanklines, sentences, words, setnum = 0,0,0,0,1
    setname = input('Please enter setname: ')
    listOfAnglicisms = open('anglicisms.txt').read().split()
    listOfGermanWords = open('haufigste.txt').read().split()
    anglicisms = []
    falsepositive = []

    def derivatesFromAnglicism(word):
        return any([word.startswith(a) for a in listOfAnglicisms])

    while os.path.isfile(str(setname+str(setnum)+".txt")) == True:

       textf = open(setname+str(setnum)+'.txt')

        for line in textf:
            line = line.lower()
            lines+=1

            if line.startswith('\n'):
                blanklines+=1
            else:
                sentences += line.count('.') + line.count('!') + line.count('?')
                words += len(line.split(None))
                anglicisms.extend([word for word in line.split() if derivatesFromAnglicism(word)])
                anglicisms = [x for x in anglicisms if x not in listOfGermanWords]

        setnum+=1

    textf.close()
    print('='*50)
    print('Lines                 : ',lines)
    print('Blanklines            : ',blanklines)
    print('Sentences             : ',sentences)
    print('Words:                : ',words)
    print('Anglicisms            : ',len(anglicisms))
    print('Words until anglicism : ',int(words)/len(anglicisms)-1)
    print('All anglicisms        :\n',Counter(anglicisms))
    print('='*50)

    while falsepositive != 'n':
        falsepositive = input('Please enter a false positive or "n" to continue: ')
        if falsepositive == 'n':
            pass
        else:
            while falsepositive in anglicisms:
                anglicisms.remove(falsepositive)


    print('='*50)
    print('Lines                 : ',lines)
    print('Blanklines            : ',blanklines)
    print('Sentences             : ',sentences)
    print('Words:                : ',words)
    print('Anglicisms            : ',len(anglicisms))
    print('Words until anglicism : ',int(words)/len(anglicisms)-1)
    print('All anglicisms        :\n',Counter(anglicisms))
    print('='*50)


    results = open(setname+'.txt', 'w')

    results.write(
        ('='*50)+
        '\n'+
        setname+'\n'+
        'Lines                 : '+lines+'\n'+
        'Blanklines            : '+blanklines+'\n'+
        'Sentences             : '+sentences+'\n'+
        'Words:                : '+words+'\n'+
        'Anglicisms            : '+len(anglicisms)+'\n'+
        'Words until anglicism : '+int(words)/len(anglicisms)-1+'\n'+
        'All anglicisms        :\n'+Counter(anglicisms)+'\n'+
        ('='*50)+
        '\n'
        )

    results.close()
```

And this is the error I get:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\anglicism_counter_5000.py", line 81, in <module>
    ('='*50)+
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly`

I have tried using str() on the variables but it didn't help. Does anybody know how to use write() properly, so this error won't occur again?

Comment: That seems like a very awkward way to create your output.

Comment: Have any suggestions?

Comment: `str.format`? Write one line at a time? Something with `'\n'.join(...)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is a little confusing. It's quoting the line `('='*50)`, but the program actually crashes at

```
'Lines                 : '+lines+'\n'+
```

(I didn't count the lines, though.)

`lines` is an integer. SO you'd need to wrap it with `str(...)`. Same for the other integers you're printing.

Comment: Thanks! I tried just that, but it didn't work, now after trying it again, it suddeny works :D